# Cron job periods

Tags: cron, cron-task, kubernetes-cronjob

I would like to run the cron job every 20 minutes between 9 AM and 11 PM and once an hour after 11 PM until 9 AM.

[cron job settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxgIs.png)

I created 2 cron jobs for the same script to achieve my goal. Did I do it correctly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There are two issues:

1. you run the script also on 23:20 and 23:40
2. you run the script twice from 09:00 till 23:00 every hour.

The way to do it is:

```
*/20 9-22   * * * command
0    0-8,23 * * * command
```

You can validate this using [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/)